# Symfony send request from an other controller api

Tags: symfony, request

I try to get a request from an other controller like this :

```
 $client = new Client();
 $watchId = $request->request->get('I_idDossierModif');
 $request->attributes->set('A_watch', $request->request->get('surveillancebundle_dossier'));
 $client->request("GET", $this->getParameter("host.api.prefix") . $this->getParameter("host.api") . "/mypath/".$watchId, array ("A_watch" => $request));
```

I want send:

```
$request->attributes->set('A_watch', $request->request->get('surveillancebundle_dossier'));
```

But when I try to get it in my other function, that return null.
I try to get it like this :

```
$request->get('A_watch')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

Save your data in the session witch persist trough the requests like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html). Or froward the request like shown in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use $client->request("GET"... for call an route api, so i think i can't use forwarding here.
For session i have add $session->set('A_watch', $request->request->get('surveillancebundle_dossier'));, but when i try to get this with $request->get('A_watch') in my other controller, that return again null :/

Comment: When you set it in the session you have to get it from it try something like $session->get('A_watch')

Comment: yes i have do it, i am fail when i write here, i get it by $session->get('A_watch') and not by $request->get('A_watch').

But like its an api, i defined $session two time, first time when i call my request get, and second time from the controller called, the problem its maybe that ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question/ You are trying to send a request from one route to another ?